# SQL CASE statement above 10 levels

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, case

I don't have a deep knowledge in SQL programming language. I'm doing a project in SQL to alter a VIEW and I need to nest a CASE statement beyond 10 levels. This is my code.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


ALTER view [dbo].[AO_VW_CONSULTA_CONTABIL_ATIVO_V3] as 
 SELECT  T.TPCODPRD, T.TPDESCR,
         E.EXCTADB, E.EXCTACR, E.EXCODHIS, E.EXCODAGE,
         E.EXNROPER, E.EXNRPARC, E.EXCNTRL, E.EXVLRMOV,
         E.EXRELATO, E.EXUSUARIO, E.EXNRBOL, E.EXCODCCUS,
         E.EXTPLNC, C.CLNOMECLI, E.EXDTMOV AS DATAMOV,
         O.OPCODPROD, O.OPCODCNV AS CODIGO,
 CASE 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000001' THEN 'CDC-CONSIGNACOES'
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000002' THEN 'CDC-FINANCIAMENTOS'
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000003' THEN 'MICROCREDITO' 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000004' THEN 'CDC-CONSIGNACAO INSS'
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000006' THEN 'CDC - REFINANCIAMENT' 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000008' THEN 'CDC - RENEGOCIA€ÇO' 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000009' THEN 'CDC - RENEG BOLETO' 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000010' THEN 'CDC-CONSIG SABEMI' 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000011' THEN 'CDC - REFIN INSS' 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000012' THEN 'CDC-CONS AUT' 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000015' THEN 'CDC-CONSIGNACOES' 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000016' THEN 'REFIN MICROCREDITO' 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000017' THEN 'CDC-COMPRA DIV INSS'
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000021' THEN 'OP DFV'
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000022' THEN 'CDC-CONSI PRIVADO'
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000023' THEN 'CDC - REFIN PRIVADO'
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000024' THEN 'MULTIPLAS LIBERAÇÕES'
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000025' THEN 'PORTABILIDADE' 
 WHEN O.OPCODPROD = '000026' THEN 'REFINANCIAMENTO MULT. LIBERAÇÕES'
 ELSE 'PRODUTO NÃO RECONHECIDO' END AS DESCRICAO

 FROM 
 dbh.FI_AT_ATIVO.dbo.ECONT E WITH(NOLOCK)
 JOIN  dbh.FI_AT_ATIVO.dbo.COPER O WITH(NOLOCK) ON E.EXNROPER = O.OPNROPER 
 JOIN  dbh.FI_AT_ATIVO.dbo.CCLIE C WITH(NOLOCK) ON O.OPCODCLI = C.CLCODCLI
 JOIN  dbh.FI_AT_aTIVO.DBO.VIEW_TPROD T WITH(NOLOCK) ON O.OPCODPROD = T.TPCODPRD
 WHERE 
  E.EXCTADB <> E.EXCTACR
  AND ( E.EXCTADB like '7.%' OR E.EXCTADB like '8.%' OR E.EXCTACR like '7.%' OR E.EXCTACR like '8.%' )
  AND E.EXRELATO IN ('01','03','04','02','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15') 

GO
```

When I execute, it doesn't say there are errors, but when I select the top 1000 header to visualize the view, it gives me this message *"case statements may only be nested to level 10"*.

Can someone explain to me why is this happening? Because before this project I've tried to do a CASE statement with more than 10 levels before and it worked.

Comment: On a side note: You do now that `WITH (NOLOCK)` is dangerous and should only be used when you really know what you are doing? Why do you allow dirty reads here? What makes this so necessary that you take the risk?

Comment: I suppose this is SQL Server? I tagged the request accordingly. If it is not, then please correct the tag.

Comment: I was given this code and asked to some columns, this part whit the WITH(NOLOCK) was already there when i started making some changes. Because of that i dont the reason to take this risk

Comment: can you provide a create table with all necessary columns for all tables and also tell us your version? a dbfiddle would also help

Comment: I cant provide u that, sorry. but the version im usin g is SMSS 18

Comment: While it is strange that SQL Server struggles with such a simple case expression, the real problem is the database. If the codes have a meaning, why then is that knowledge not stored in a database table, but must be hard-coded in queries? Create a proper table, add a proper foreign key constraint, join that table to your other tables, and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is weird, because your `CASE` expression is not nested. Well, maybe the DBMS nests them behin the scenes. You can probably circumvent this with the other form of a `CASE` expression (`CASE value WHEN ... THEN ... WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END`:

```
CASE O.opcodprod
  WHEN '000001' THEN 'CDC-CONSIGNACOES'
  WHEN '000002' THEN 'CDC-FINANCIAMENTOS'
  WHEN '000003' THEN 'MICROCREDITO' 
  WHEN '000004' THEN 'CDC-CONSIGNACAO INSS'
  WHEN '000006' THEN 'CDC - REFINANCIAMENT' 
  WHEN '000008' THEN 'CDC - RENEGOCIA€ÇO' 
  WHEN '000009' THEN 'CDC - RENEG BOLETO' 
  WHEN '000010' THEN 'CDC-CONSIG SABEMI' 
  WHEN '000011' THEN 'CDC - REFIN INSS' 
  WHEN '000012' THEN 'CDC-CONS AUT' 
  WHEN '000015' THEN 'CDC-CONSIGNACOES' 
  WHEN '000016' THEN 'REFIN MICROCREDITO' 
  WHEN '000017' THEN 'CDC-COMPRA DIV INSS'
  WHEN '000021' THEN 'OP DFV'
  WHEN '000022' THEN 'CDC-CONSI PRIVADO'
  WHEN '000023' THEN 'CDC - REFIN PRIVADO'
  WHEN '000024' THEN 'MULTIPLAS LIBERAÇÕES'
  WHEN '000025' THEN 'PORTABILIDADE' 
  WHEN '000026' THEN 'REFINANCIAMENTO MULT. LIBERAÇÕES'
  ELSE 'PRODUTO NÃO RECONHECIDO'
END AS descricao
```

The other solution, the one that I'd actually prefer, would be to have a *table* for the codes and descriptions that you'd simply join.

Comment: Good point re: "behind the scenes". I was thinking recursive CTE myself... and one table is named `dbh.FI_AT_aTIVO.DBO.VIEW_TPROD`, so maybe there's a view doing something wonky?

Comment: Maybe it is but this table can affect in another colums from other tabel? It is given the "T" name and the one in the CASE statement is from another table "O" so i thought that it would not cause problems with the rest of the code

Comment: This solution didnt worked, it is still giving me the same error, "case statements may only be nested to level 10", when i tried it whit half of the WHEN statements it works just fine

Comment: Then take the other option and create a table with the codes and descriptions. As mentioned, this approach is preferable anyway in my opinion.

Comment: I think that there might be something else going on. Can you provide a [mre] @DiogoMiranda ?

Comment: @Larnu: I just found this: https://en.dirceuresende.com/blog/sql-server-statements-could-not-be-prepared-case-expressions-may-only-be-nested-to-level-10/. They show that SQL Server really changes `case when <expression 1> then <block 1> when < expression 2> then <block 2> when ...` to a nested `case when <expression 1> then <block 1> else when < expression 2> then <block 2> else when ...` internally.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the sentiment that others have expressed elsewhere in comments on this question that these mappings should really be stored in a first-class table in your database. That said, this should be a way around your problem:

```sql
SELECT  T.TPCODPRD, T.TPDESCR,
         E.EXCTADB, E.EXCTACR, E.EXCODHIS, E.EXCODAGE,
         E.EXNROPER, E.EXNRPARC, E.EXCNTRL, E.EXVLRMOV,
         E.EXRELATO, E.EXUSUARIO, E.EXNRBOL, E.EXCODCCUS,
         E.EXTPLNC, C.CLNOMECLI, E.EXDTMOV AS DATAMOV,
         O.OPCODPROD, O.OPCODCNV AS CODIGO,
         COALESCE(mapping.DESCRICAO, 'PRODUTO NÃO RECONHECIDO')
 FROM 
 dbh.FI_AT_ATIVO.dbo.ECONT E WITH(NOLOCK)
 JOIN  dbh.FI_AT_ATIVO.dbo.COPER O WITH(NOLOCK) ON E.EXNROPER = O.OPNROPER 
 JOIN  dbh.FI_AT_ATIVO.dbo.CCLIE C WITH(NOLOCK) ON O.OPCODCLI = C.CLCODCLI
 JOIN  dbh.FI_AT_aTIVO.DBO.VIEW_TPROD T WITH(NOLOCK) ON O.OPCODPROD = T.TPCODPRD
 
 outer apply (
    select DESCRICAO from (values
        ('000001', 'CDC-CONSIGNACOES'),
        ('000002', 'CDC-FINANCIAMENTOS'),
        ('000003', 'MICROCREDITO' ),
        ('000004', 'CDC-CONSIGNACAO INSS'),
        ('000006', 'CDC - REFINANCIAMENT' ),
        ('000008', 'CDC - RENEGOCIA€ÇO' ),
        ('000009', 'CDC - RENEG BOLETO' ),
        ('000010', 'CDC-CONSIG SABEMI' ),
        ('000011', 'CDC - REFIN INSS' ),
        ('000012', 'CDC-CONS AUT' ),
        ('000015', 'CDC-CONSIGNACOES' ),
        ('000016', 'REFIN MICROCREDITO' ),
        ('000017', 'CDC-COMPRA DIV INSS'),
        ('000021', 'OP DFV'),
        ('000022', 'CDC-CONSI PRIVADO'),
        ('000023', 'CDC - REFIN PRIVADO'),
        ('000024', 'MULTIPLAS LIBERAÇÕES'),
        ('000025', 'PORTABILIDADE' ),
        ('000026', 'REFINANCIAMENTO MULT. LIBERAÇÕES')
    ) as foobar(OPCODPROD, DESCRICAO)
    where foobar.OPCODPROD = O.OPCODPROD
) as mapping

 WHERE 
  E.EXCTADB <> E.EXCTACR
  AND ( E.EXCTADB like '7.%' OR E.EXCTADB like '8.%' OR E.EXCTACR like '7.%' OR E.EXCTACR like '8.%' )
  AND E.EXRELATO IN ('01','03','04','02','05','06','07','08','09','10','11','12','13','14','15')
```

I chose to use `outer apply` here for no particular reason. Equally valid approaches would be to use either a CTE or an inline derived table and use a `left join` instead.